# Save Order item custom field in Woocommerce Admin order pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

I have add custom fields in back office order for each line products :
[image]
<sub>(source: [com-pac.ovh](https://www.com-pac.ovh/TARDY/Sans-titre-1.jpg))</sub>

My code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'cfwc_create_custom_field' );
function cfwc_create_custom_field() {

    $args = array(
        'id' => 'custom_text_field_title',
        'label' => __( 'Custom Text Field Title', 'cfwc' ),
        'class' => 'cfwc-custom-field',
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'description' => __( 'Enter the title of your custom text field.', 'ctwc' ),
    );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to save this fields.

Any help?

Comment: right below you example, in the documentation

Comment: I have already try but it don't work...my values return to zero...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update 2021 *(using CRUD Objects methods)*

To add and save a custom field to order "line items" in admin order edit pages you will use something like:

```
// Add a custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'add_order_item_custom_field', 10, 2 );
function add_order_item_custom_field( $item_id, $item ) {
    // Targeting line items type only
    if( $item->get_type() !== 'line_item' ) return;

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => 'cfield_oitem_'.$item_id,
        'label'         => __( 'Custom Text Field Title', 'cfwc' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Enter the title of your custom text field.', 'ctwc' ),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
        'class'         => 'woocommerce',
        'value'         => wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_custom_field' ),
    ) );
}

// Save the custom field value
add_action('save_post', 'save_order_item_custom_field_value', 10000, 2 );
function save_order_item_custom_field_value( $post_id, $post ){
    if ( 'shop_order' !== $post->post_type )
        return $post_id;

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_order', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        if( isset( $_POST['cfield_oitem_'.$item_id] ) ) {
            $item->update_meta_data( '_custom_field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cfield_oitem_'.$item_id] ) );
            $item->save();
        }
    }
    $order->save();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

#### Additions

Optionally Keep the new meta key/value as hidden in backend

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta', 'additional_hidden_order_itemmeta', 10, 1 );
function additional_hidden_order_itemmeta( $args ) {
    $args[] = '_custom_field';
    return $args;
}
```

Optionally Change the displayed meta key label

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key', 20, 3 );
function filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {
    // Change displayed label for specific order item meta key
    if( is_admin() && $item->get_type() === 'line_item' && $meta->key === '_custom_field' ) {
        $display_key = __("Some label", "woocommerce" );
    }
    return $display_key;
}
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec instead of "save_post_shop_order" which trigger when we save the entire order, do you know the hook name which trigger when user tries to edit and save the line item in the line item view? the save button appear at the bottom of the all the line item.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec hi, i follow your code but i got something really weird. In the 'save_order_item_custom_field_value' hook, i update my item meta and check the updated value using 'wc_get_order_item_meta'. It seems to be updated to new value, but  when i visit the order page, the value revert to the previous  value. Any idea why?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I wonder if you can test does it work if we update the text field after the first save. I started a complete fresh site using default theme and only woocommerce is activated with the code paste in function.php. It works only for the first save, but i couldn't update the value in the subsequent order update from admin dashboard. The behavior is consistent across local and remote hosts.

Comment: I tracked my meta value in post.php. It seems to be after the 'save_post_shop_order' and before 'save_post' hook the meta value is correct with updated value. But after 'save_post' hook, the meta value is reverted back to previous's (before update) value. So instead of using 'save_post_shop_order' hook, I use 'save_post' to correct the update behavior.