# WooCommerce custom order itemmeta display my account view order page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I created a custom field for the ecommerce admin order item meta. Everything is fine.

I would like to display the Custom Fields MetaValue on My Account's Order Details page. But nothing is being displayed. Based on [Save Order item custom field in Woocommerce Admin order pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54406630/11987538) answer code, this is my attempt

```
function add_order_item_custom_field( $item_id, $item ) {
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
    'id'            => 'v_number'.$item_id,
    'label'         => __( 'V Number : ', 'ctxt' ),
    'description'   => __( 'Enter the title of your custom text field.', 'ctxt' ),
    'desc_tip'      => true,
    'class'         => 'v_number_class',
    'value'         => wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_v_number' ),
) );
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'add_order_item_custom_field', 10, 2 );

// Save the custom field value
function save_order_item_custom_field_value( $post_id, $post ){
$order = wc_get_order( $post_id );
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['v_number'.$item_id] ) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( '_v_number', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['v_number'.$item_id] ) );
        $item->save();
    }
}
$order->save();
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_order_item_custom_field_value' );
```

[image]

```
// Display meta my account view order page
 printf ( 
'<p><a>V Number :  <strong>' . $order->get_meta('_v_number') . '</strong></a></p>'
);
```

[image]

Comment: **1)** If you are using existing code, please cite the source, because it gives proper credit to the author. **2)** I get the first part of your code, but _"Display meta my account view order page"_ and then you only add 1 line of code in your question. Please be clearer about that, what specific location is it about?  **3)** If you want to display this under the product name, this is already done automatically. **4)** In the first part of your code you save the meta with `$item->update_meta_data()`, in the second part you use `$order->get_meta()`, `$item` is not the same as `$order`.

Comment: I would like to display this custom field value header on the Order Details page of My Account. But after trying a lot, it is not working.  Any idea please ..??

Comment: I would like to display this custom field value below each product on the Order Details page of My Account. But after trying a lot, it is not working. Any idea please ..?? –

Comment: As I have already indicated. If you want to display this below the product name, on the order details page from my account, this happens already automatically, with the code you use. If this is not the case for you, then this deviates from the default operation of WooCommerce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should print your custom order meta value.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'print_custom_order_meta' );
function print_custom_order_meta( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        echo 'V Number for '. $item->get_name() .' - ' . $item->get_meta( '_v_number', true ) . '<br>';
    }
}
```

**edit**

for need to show metavalue after each product item you need to hook with a different action like this.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'show_order_meta', 11, 3);
function show_order_meta( $item_id, $item, $order ) {
    echo '<br>V Number for '. $item->get_name() .' - ' . $item->get_meta( '_v_number', true ) . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Excellent work. That's exactly what I wanted. But there is a problem here. How can I display the metavalue of each field below each product / item?

Comment: Dear, thank you very much. The problem has been solved. If you don't mind, can I know another thing related to this?